# Mongoose: $inc not decrementing when using -1

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `User` collection that contains a `msg` object. This object contains two properties: `'unread'` and `'blockedBy'`. The `'unread'` property is of `Number` type and holds the amount of unread messages a user currently has.

When a user calls the messaging inbox service (`api/messages/inbox/:messageId`) I want to reduce this number in the `User` collection to keep things in sync.

I have tried every thing I can think of. From using a `User.update()` statement to `User.findById(user.save())` to `user.markModified('msg.unread')` and nothing works.

The callback on the `user.save()` shows the expected result, but the data is not committed to MongoDB.

Here is the code:

```
User.findById(req.session.uid, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }

                user.msg.unread = user.msg.unread - 1;
                //let mongoose know that this has been updated, so it will be committed to DB
                user.markModified('msg');

                user.save(function (err, user) {

                    if (err) {
                        return next(err);
                    }

                    message.read = true;
                    message.save(function (err, message) {
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        }

                        res.json({
                            'error': false,
                            'data': message
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
```

And here is the relevant portion of the User model:

```
msg: {
    unread: {type: Number, default: 0},
    blockedBy: {type: Array}
},
```

Comment: You mention $inc in title, but you're not using it in your example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)** module to simplify this task, in particular you'd need to use **[`async.series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback)** since you want to run multiple tasks that depend on each other i.e. updating the `User` model's `msg` object before updating the `Message` model:

```
var async = require("async"),
    userId = req.session.uid,
    locals = {};
async.series(
    [
        // Update user 
        function(callback) {
            var update = { "$inc": { "msg.unread": -1 } },
                query = { "_id": userId };              
            User.update(query, update, function (err, result) {
                if (err) return callback(err);                
                callback();
            });
        },
        // Modify message here (won't be called before task 1's "task callback" has been called)
        function(callback) {
            var update = { "$set": { "read": true } },
                query = { "_id": messageId },
                options = { "new": true }; //if true, return the modified document rather than the original. defaults to false
            Message.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, message) {
                if (err) return callback(err);                                   
                locals.data = message;
                locals.error = false;
                callback();
            });
        },
    ], function(err) { //This function gets called after the two tasks have called their "task callbacks"
        if (err) return next(err);
        //Here locals will be populated with 'data' and 'error'
        res.json(locals);
    }
);
```

Comment: I installed async and tested this solution... seems to do the trick! I'll have to review the rest of my code to see where I can take further advantage of this async chaining capability.

Answer (score 0):

> The callback on the user.save() shows the expected result, but the data is not committed to MongoDB.

This indicates that you are successfully decremented the value, but are most likely undoing it with a `save` later on.

For example if you update the database directly, but not your `user` object, and then save the `user` object, it will overwrite the entire user object in the database and revert to the old undecremented value.